# How to pull specific information from an output in Python

Tags: python, parsing, blender, mocha.js, pyparsing

So I have a code that gives an output, and what I need to do is pull the information out in between the commas, assign them to a variable that changes dynamically when called... here is my code:

```
import re

data_directory = 'Z:/Blender_Roto/'
data_file = 'diving_board.shape4ae'
fullpath = data_directory + data_file


print("====init=====")

file = open(fullpath)
for line in file:
current_line = line

# massive room for optimized code here.

# this assumes the last element of the line containing the words
# "Units Per Second" is the number we are looking for.
# this is a non float number, generally.
if current_line.find("Units Per Second") != -1:
    fps = line_split = float(current_line.split()[-1])
    print("Frames Per Second:", fps)

# source dimensions
if current_line.find("Source Width") != -1:
    source_width = line_split = int(current_line.split()[-1])
    print("Source Width:", source_width)

if current_line.find("Source Height") != -1:
    source_height = line_split = int(current_line.split()[-1])
    print("Source Height:", source_height)

# aspect ratios
if current_line.find("Source Pixel Aspect Ratio") != -1:
    source_px_aspect = line_split = int(current_line.split()[-1])
    print("Source Pixel Aspect Ratio:", source_px_aspect)

if current_line.find("Comp Pixel Aspect Ratio") != -1:
    comp_aspect = line_split = int(current_line.split()[-1])
    print("Comp Pixel Aspect Ratio:", comp_aspect)


# assumption, ae file can contain multiple mocha shapes.
# without knowing the exact format i will limit the script
# to deal with one mocha shape being animated N frames.

# this gathers the shape details, and frame number but does not
# include error checking yet.
if current_line.find("XSpline") != -1:

    # record the frame number.

    frame = re.search("\s*(\d*)\s*XSpline", current_line)
    if frame.group(1) != None:
        frame = frame.group(1)
        print("frame:", frame)


    # pick part the part of the line that deals with geometry
    match = re.search("XSpline\((.+)\)\n", current_line)

    line_to_strip = match.group(1)
    points = re.findall('(\(.*?\))', line_to_strip)

    print(len(points))
    for point in points:
        print(point)
    print("="*40)

file.close()
```

This gives me the output:

```
====init=====
Frames Per Second: 24.0
Source Width: 2048
Source Height: 778
Source Pixel Aspect Ratio: 1
Comp Pixel Aspect Ratio: 1
frame: 20
5
(0.793803,0.136326,0,0.5,0)
(0.772345,0.642332,0,0.5,0)
(0.6436,0.597615,0,0.5,0)
(0.70082,0.143387,0,0.5,0.25)
(0.70082,0.112791,0,0.5,0)
========================================
```

So what I need for example is to be able to assign (0.793803, 0.136326, 0,  0.5, 0) to (1x,1y,1z,1w,1s), (0.772345,0.642332,0,0.5,0) to (2x, 2y, 2z, 2w, 2s) etc so that no matter what numbers are filling those positions they will take on that value.

here is the code I need to put those numbers into:

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Name:        Mocha Rotoscoping Via Blender
# Purpose:     Make rotoscoping more efficient
#
# Author:      Jeff Owens
#
# Created:     11/07/2011
# Copyright:   (c) jeff.owens 2011
# Licence:     Grasshorse
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os
import parser
sys.path.append('Z:\_protomotion\Prog\HelperScripts')
import GetDir
sys.path.append('Z:\_tutorials\01\tut01_001\prod\Blender_Test')
filename = 'diving_board.shape4ae'
infile = 'Z:\_tutorials\01\tut01_001\prod\Blender_Test'
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

#below are taken from mocha export
x_width =2048
y_height = 778
z_depth = 0
frame = 20

def readText():
text_file = open('diving_board.shape4ae', 'r')
lines = text_file.readlines()
print (lines)
print (len.lines)
for line in lines:
    print (line)

##sets points final x,y,z value taken from mocha export for blender interface

point1x = (0.642706 * x_width)
point1y = (0.597615 * y_height)
point1z = (0 * z_depth) 

point2x = (0.770557 * x_width)
point2y = (0.647039 * y_height)
point2z = (0 * z_depth)

point3x = (0.794697 * x_width)
point3y = (0.0869024 * y_height)
point3z = (0 * z_depth)


point4x = (0.707973* x_width)
point4y = (0.0751348 * y_height)
point4z = (0 * z_depth)


w = 1 # weight
listOfVectors = [Vector((point1x,point1y,point1z)),Vector((point2x,point2y,point2z)),Vector((point3x,point3    y,point3z)),Vector((point4x,point4y,point4z)), Vector((point1x,point1y,point1z))]

def MakePolyLine(objname, curvename, cList):
curvedata = bpy.data.curves.new(name=curvename, type='CURVE')
curvedata.dimensions = '3D'

objectdata = bpy.data.objects.new(objname, curvedata)
objectdata.location = (0,0,0) #object origin
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(objectdata)

polyline = curvedata.splines.new('POLY')
polyline.points.add(len(cList)-1)
for num in range(len(cList)):
    x, y, z = cList[num]
    polyline.points[num].co = (x, y, z, w)

MakePolyLine("NameOfMyCurveObject", "NameOfMyCurve", listOfVectors)
```

So where I have my vector I would like to be able to place (p.x, p.y,0.z,p.w,p.s) then (p2.x,p2.y,p2.zp2.wp2.s) etc so that it can change per the number given

Any help will be great.. thank you in advance!

-jeff

Comment: Parsing text in Python is actually quite easy, but you'll have to come up with a method on your own. From the top of my head I would attack this problem with splitting the string up on newlines (using [str.split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)), then parsing each line individually using a combination str.split and simple inspection. As long as the text doesn't change in format, you can write your parser for this specific case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of *printing* each output, you can create point objects and index them by name.  For example:

```
>>> class Point:
...     def __init__(self, t):
...         (self.x,self.y,self.z,self.w,self.s) = t
... 
>>> p = Point( (3,4,5,3,1) )
>>> p.w
3
```

You can place these point objects in an array, then access components by

```
myPoints[3].x
```

**ADDENDUM**

If it is important to you *not* to pull the points from an array, but rather use actual variable names, you *can* do the following, where `points` is your **array of tuples**:

```
(p0x,p0y,p0z,p0w,p0s) = points[0]
(p1x,p1y,p1z,p1w,p1s) = points[1]
(p2x,p2y,p2z,p2w,p2s) = points[2]
...
```

and so on.

Do consider whether this is an appropriate approach though.  Having a point class allows you to have any number of points.  With defined variable names, creating an unbounded number of these things on the fly is possible but almost always a bad idea.  Here is a caveat about doing so: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2005-January/035232.html.

When you have an array of point objects you do what you want much better!  For example you can do the following:

```
myPoints[i].y = 12
```

thereby changing the y-coordinate of the ith point.  This is next to impossible when you have fixed the variable names.  Hope that helps!  (And hope I understand your clarification! Let me know if not....)

Comment: Great, thank you very much, that should do the trick.. I'll let you know for sure though

Comment: I should have also noted in my question the other code I have which can be found here: http://www.pasteall.org/23850/python , so my goal is to take the data points given from that file and be able to name them dynamically to a vector so it changes every frame

Comment: `namedtuple` makes the creation of the Point class even easier:  `Point = namedtuple("Point", "x y z w s")`.

Comment: Didn't know about that one.  Fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your code right, the relevant portion is the loop at the end that produces your tuples.

```
data = []
for point in points:
    data.append(point)    
    print(point)
```

That will create a new list and add each tuple to the list. So, `data[0]` holds `(0.793803,0.136326,0,0.5,0)` and `data[0][0]` holds `0.793803`.

Comment: data[0][0] holds the value 0, data[0][1] holds . , data[0][2] holds 7, etc

Comment: I should have also noted in my question the other code I have which can be found here: pasteall.org/23850/python , so my goal is to take the data points given from that file and be able to name them dynamically to a vector so it changes every frame

Comment: If points are tuples, that shouldn't happen. Are they strings? If so, then the append step will need parsing of some kind.